# get sent or recieved emails from sendgrid

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

We're using SendGrid for email service for a project backend.

Now, we want to set up e2e tests for the project. To get a well-verified user, we have to know the verification code sent to the user's email at the time of the registration.

I've tried with the `messages` endpoint as:

```sh
curl --request GET \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/messages \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

But the response says:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"authorization required"}]}
```

Is there any way that we can get the sent emails using the SendGrid API?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of [the documentation for the email activity API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-email-activity-api) it says:

> In order to gain access to the Email Activity Feed API, you must purchase [additional email activity history](https://sendgrid.com/solutions/add-ons/30-days-additional-email-activity-history/).

I would guess that you are receiving that error because your account does not have that additional email activity history add-on.

Comment: true. but so sad to know that the activity API is a paid feature. e2e testing people will not be encouraged by this imho.